# Get TIMEDIFF() in MySQL from all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max, min

I have a `user_tasks` table like so:

```
| id | user_id | created_at          | status   |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 2020-08-04 13:00:00 | started  |
| 2  | 1       | 2020-08-04 13:00:00 | pending  |
| 3  | 1       | 2020-08-04 13:00:10 | pending  |
| 4  | 1       | 2020-08-04 13:00:40 | pending  |
| 5  | 1       | 2020-08-04 13:00:41 | finished |
```

I would like to get the difference between the last `pending` status and the first `pending` status in seconds. Therefore I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    TIMEDIFF(
    (SELECT created_at FROM user_tasks WHERE user_id = 1 AND `status` = 'pending' ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1), 
    (SELECT created_at FROM user_tasks WHERE user_id = 1 AND `status` = 'pending' ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1)
    ) AS pending_time
```

This gets me the result in seconds `(-00:00:40)`, as expected. However, how can I achieve this for every `user_task`?

Ultimately, I am trying to get the average `pending_time` from all `user_tasks` in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow you correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select user_id, timediff(max(created_at), min(created_at)) pending_time
from user_tasks
where status = 'pending'
group by user_id
```